# How to retain the listview and the child fragment state after updating the contents of listview?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have a listView of items.Each item has two separate fragment inside it and gets visible when the item is clicked. Inside a fragment there is another ListView and a button. The button displays a dialog through which ListView inside the fragment gets populated.The problem is when the dialog closes,the parent listview gets refreshed and as a result fragment visibility is gone. I have to click the parent list view item again to see the fragment and its content. I want the Fragment view and its updated content remain viewed after the dialog is dismissed. So someone please help me in it.

The following is my parent listView class:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Due extends FragmentActivity implements
        OutletformAddDialog_due.DonebuttonListener {
    TextView headerView;
    View tempstore, imagetempstore;
    OutletformAddDialog_due selectedOutlet;
    Fragment fr;
    public BaseAdapter dueadapter;
    ListView Duelist;
    Boolean DuedetailFlag = false, OrderdetailFlag = false;

    TextView DueDetailsRight, DueDetailsTop, DueDetailsBottom,
            DueDetailsrightHorizontal, OrderDetailsleft, OrderDetailstop,
            OrderDetailsBottom, OrderDetailsleftHorizontal, DueDetailsButton,
            OrderDetailsButton, btnDueNav, tvOutletName;
    Button DuetoCallCard;

    int index;

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    private String order_id;
    private String outlet_id;
    private String amount;
    private String date;
    private int count = 0;
    private View lvNavigation;

    boolean formDashboard = false;

    ArrayList<Payment> dueArray = new ArrayList<Payment>();
    ArrayList<DueItem> tempdueArray = new ArrayList<DueItem>();
    ArrayList<String> navigationList;
    NavigationAdapter adapter;

    int prevItem, currentItem;
    View btnDuetoCallCard;
    private ImageView home;
    String stateStore = "";
    TextView totalCollectedDue;
    TextView orderDueAmmount;

    ViewGroup header;
    private View clickedHeaderView;

    FragmentManager fm;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    public String getheaderDueamount() {
        return orderDueAmmount.getText().toString();
    }

    public void setheaderDueamount(String amount) {
        orderDueAmmount.setText(amount);
    }

    // public void setDueList(int position) {
    // dueadapter.getItem(position)
    // }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.duea_amount_layout);

        DuetoCallCard = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDuetoCallCard);

        DuetoCallCard.bringToFront();

        Duelist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.due_layout_listView);

        tvOutletName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textviewoutletname);

        home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btndueHome);
        home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(Due.this,
                        MainActivity.class));
                intent.putExtra("home", true);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (b != null) {
            formDashboard = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("fromDashboard");
        }

        if (formDashboard) {
            // spinRoute.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // spinOutlet.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // Outlet1542

            selectedOutlet = new OutletformAddDialog_due();
            selectedOutlet.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");

        } else {
            populateArray();
        }

        btnDuetoCallCard = findViewById(R.id.btnDuetoCallCard);

        initArrays();

        // for disappearing the big circular button
        Duelist.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount) {
                    // End has been reached
                    // btnaddOutlet.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Outlet_List.this,
                    // android.R.anim.fade_out));
                    btnDuetoCallCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    // btnaddOutlet.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Outlet_List.this,
                    // android.R.anim.fade_in));
                    btnDuetoCallCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                if (visibleItemCount == totalItemCount)
                    btnDuetoCallCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }

    void populateArray() {
        dueadapter = new BaseAdapter() {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                // if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dueamounts_list_item,
                        null);
                // }

                TextView orderNo = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvdueOrderNo);
                TextView orderDate = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvdueDate);
                orderDueAmmount = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvRemainingDueAmmount);
                ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.dueImageButton);

                orderNo.setText("Order "
                        + dueArray.get(position).getOrder_id().getId());
                orderDate.setText(dueArray.get(position).getDate());
                Double dueAmount = dueArray.get(position).getAmount();
                orderDueAmmount.setText(formatDoubleValues(dueAmount));

                // old way
                // orderNo.setText("" + dueArray.get(position).getOrder());
                // orderDate.setText(dueArray.get(position).getDate());
                // orderAmmount.setText(dueArray.get(position).getAmmount());

                header = (ViewGroup) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header);
                header.setId(position);
                header.setOnClickListener(due_header_clicked);
                ViewGroup body = (ViewGroup) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.body);

                View Headerparent = (View) header.getParent();

                View image = findViewById(R.id.dueImageButton);
                View TAB_Orderdetail = body.findViewById(R.id.btnOrderDetails);
                View TAB_Duedetail = body.findViewById(R.id.btnDueDetails);
                TAB_Orderdetail.setOnClickListener(change_fragment_listener);
                TAB_Duedetail.setOnClickListener(change_fragment_listener);
                // imgbtn.setOnClickListener(due_header_clicked);

                View placeHolder = convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.duefragment_placeholder);

                int id = 10000 + position;
                placeHolder.setId(id);
                dueArray.get(position).setPlaceHolder(id);

                Payment item = dueArray.get(position);

                if (stateStore.equals("" + position)) {
//                  header.performClick();
                    body.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     header.performClick();

                } else {
                    body.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                // totalCollectedDue = (TextView) convertView
                // .findViewById(R.id.tvTotalCollectedDueAmount);

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return dueArray.get(position);

            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return dueArray.size();
            }

        };

        Duelist.setAdapter(dueadapter);
        dueadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Duelist.setDivider(null);
        Duelist.setDividerHeight(0);
    }

    int headerIndex = 0;
    // View headerView;
    int placeHolder_id = 0;
    public OnClickListener due_header_clicked = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onHeaderClicked(v);
            clickedHeaderView = v;

        }
    };

    public void onHeaderClicked(View v) {
        index = v.getId();
        headerIndex = index;
        // fr = dueArray.get(index).getDueFragment();

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("index", headerIndex);
        fr = tempdueArray.get(index).getDueFragment(headerIndex);
        // fr.setArguments(bundle);
        // tempdueArray.get(index).setDue_fragment(headerIndex);

        Due.this.placeHolder_id = dueArray.get(index).getPlaceHolder();
        final Payment item = dueArray.get(index);

        // saving the header clicked position for later use
        stateStore = "" + v.getId();

        View view = (View) v.getParent();

        TextView headerDueamount = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tvRemainingDueAmmount);
        headerView = headerDueamount;

        DueDetailsRight = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvduedetialright);
        DueDetailsTop = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvdeudetailstop);
        DueDetailsBottom = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tvdeudetailsBottom1);
        DueDetailsrightHorizontal = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tvDuedetailslefthorizontal);
        OrderDetailsBottom = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tvorderdetailBottom);
        OrderDetailstop = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvorderdetailtop);
        OrderDetailsleft = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tvOrderdetailsleft);
        OrderDetailsleftHorizontal = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tvDuedetailsrighthorizontal);

        final View body = view.findViewById(R.id.body);
        View image = view.findViewById(R.id.dueImageButton);
        View TAB_Orderdetail = body.findViewById(R.id.btnOrderDetails);
        View TAB_Duedetail = body.findViewById(R.id.btnDueDetails);
        TAB_Orderdetail.setOnClickListener(change_fragment_listener);
        TAB_Duedetail.setOnClickListener(change_fragment_listener);

        if (body.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
            if (tempstore != null) {
                tempstore.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imagetempstore
                        .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_due_dropdown_icon);
            }

            tempstore = body;
            imagetempstore = image;
            body.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // if (fr == null) {

            View test = (View) v.getParent().getParent();
            DueDetailsButton = (TextView) test
                    .findViewById(R.id.btnOrderDetails);

            OrderDetailsleft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            OrderDetailstop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            DueDetailsBottom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            OrderDetailsleftHorizontal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            DueDetailsRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            DueDetailsTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            OrderDetailsBottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            DueDetailsrightHorizontal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();

            // fr = dueArray.get(index).getOrderFragment();
            // fragmentTransaction.replace(item.getPlaceHolder(), fr);
            // fragmentTransaction.commit();

            // fr = dueArray.get(index).getDueFragment();

            fr = tempdueArray.get(index).getDueFragment(headerIndex);
            fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(item.getPlaceHolder(), fr);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

            image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_expand_icon);

        } else {
            image.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_due_dropdown_icon);
            body.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    }

    public OnClickListener change_fragment_listener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeFargment(v);
        }
    };

    public void changeFargment(View v) {

        View test = (View) v.getParent().getParent();

        DueDetailsRight = (TextView) test.findViewById(R.id.tvduedetialright);
        DueDetailsTop = (TextView) test.findViewById(R.id.tvdeudetailstop);
        DueDetailsBottom = (TextView) test
                .findViewById(R.id.tvdeudetailsBottom1);
        DueDetailsrightHorizontal = (TextView) test
                .findViewById(R.id.tvDuedetailslefthorizontal);
        OrderDetailsBottom = (TextView) test
                .findViewById(R.id.tvorderdetailBottom);
        OrderDetailstop = (TextView) test.findViewById(R.id.tvorderdetailtop);
        OrderDetailsleft = (TextView) test
                .findViewById(R.id.tvOrderdetailsleft);
        OrderDetailsleftHorizontal = (TextView) test
                .findViewById(R.id.tvDuedetailsrighthorizontal);

        DueDetailsButton = (TextView) test.findViewById(R.id.btnDueDetails);
        OrderDetailsButton = (TextView) test.findViewById(R.id.btnOrderDetails);

        OrderDetailsButton = (TextView) test.findViewById(R.id.btnOrderDetails);

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnOrderDetails:

            DueDetailsButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8e8f92"));
            OrderDetailsButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#050708"));

            // Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            // bundle.putInt("index", headerIndex);

            // fr = dueArray.get(headerIndex).getOrderFragment();
            fr = tempdueArray.get(headerIndex).getOrderFragment(headerIndex);
            // fr.setArguments(bundle);
            DueDetailsRight.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            DueDetailsTop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            OrderDetailsBottom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            DueDetailsrightHorizontal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            OrderDetailsleft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            OrderDetailstop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            DueDetailsBottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            OrderDetailsleftHorizontal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;
        case R.id.btnDueDetails:

            OrderDetailsButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#8e8f92"));
            DueDetailsButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#050708"));

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("index", headerIndex);

            // fr = dueArray.get(headerIndex).getDueFragment();
            fr = tempdueArray.get(headerIndex).getDueFragment(headerIndex);
            fr.setArguments(bundle);

            OrderDetailsleft.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            OrderDetailstop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            DueDetailsBottom.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            OrderDetailsleftHorizontal.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            DueDetailsRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            DueDetailsTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            OrderDetailsBottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            DueDetailsrightHorizontal.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;
        case R.id.btnCollection:

            break;
        case R.id.btndueHome:
            Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(Due.this, MainActivity.class));
            intent.putExtra("home", true);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;

        }

        // DueDetail.total = 0;
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(Due.this.placeHolder_id, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }

    public void buttonClickActions(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Due.this, CallCard.class));
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDoneButtonClick(DialogFragment dialog, String outlet,
            String outletId) {

        tvOutletName.setText(outlet);
        outlet_id = outletId;

        populateArray();

    }

    List<Payment> dueList;

    public void initArrays() {
        dueList = Entity.query(Payment.class).executeMulti();

        // initializing the arraylist with object values
        for (int i = 0; i < dueList.size(); i++) {

            dueArray.add(dueList.get(i));

            DueItem dt = new DueItem();
            // dt.setOrder("order " + dueList.get(i).getOrder_id());
            // dt.setDate("21July,2015" + dueList.get(i).getDate());
            // dt.setAmmount("BDT" + dueList.get(i).getAmount());
            tempdueArray.add(dt);
        }

    }

    public String formatDoubleValues(Double myDouble) {
        DecimalFormat myFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        return myFormat.format(myDouble);
    }

}
```

And the following class is one of the fragment class that is updating the fragment ListView and the parent Listview it is in.

```
public class DueDetail extends Fragment {

    BaseAdapter dueDetailAdapter;
    ListView dueDetailList;
    TextView collectionbtn;
    TextView totalInitialDue;
    CheckBox cbCash, cbCheque;
    private String dueAmmount;
    double total, totalremainingDue;
    int currentDueOnOrder = 100000;

    ArrayList<DueCollection> arrayDueDetail = new ArrayList<DueCollection>();
    ArrayList<Payment> arrayPayment = new ArrayList<Payment>();
    List<DueCollection> duelist;
    List<Payment> paymentlist;
    private TextView TotalCollectedDue;
    Formater fObj = new Formater();
    int currentPositon;
    int position;
    Due dueActivity;
    OrderModel om;
    DueCollection odi;
    boolean setClicked = false;

    public DueDetail(int pos) {
        //
        duelist = Entity.query(DueCollection.class).executeMulti();
        for (int i = 0; i < duelist.size(); i++) {
            // if (duelist.get(i).getAmount() != null) {
            int postion = duelist.get(i).getPayment_id().getId();
            if (postion == pos + 1) {
                arrayDueDetail.add(duelist.get(i));
            }

        }

        paymentlist = Entity.query(Payment.class).executeMulti();
        for (int i = 0; i < paymentlist.size(); i++) {
            arrayPayment.add(paymentlist.get(i));
        }

        // for calculating the total of collected due in the duedetail
        // fragment
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayDueDetail.size(); i++) {
            if (arrayDueDetail.get(i).getAmount() != null) {
                int dueAmount = Integer.parseInt(arrayDueDetail.get(i)
                        .getAmount());
                total += dueAmount;
            }

        }
        //
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.due_amounts_duedetails_history,
                container, false);
        this.view = view;

        dueActivity = (Due) getActivity();
        position = dueActivity.getIndex();

        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");

        totalInitialDue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRemainingDue);

        totalInitialDue.setText("BDT "
                + arrayPayment.get(position).getInitialDue());
        TotalCollectedDue = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tvTotalCollectedDueAmount);
        String totalduecollection = amountFormatter(total);
        TotalCollectedDue.setText("BDT " + totalduecollection);

        updateUI();
        return view;
    }

    View view;

    public void updateUI() {
        if (view == null)
            return;
        collectionbtn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCollection);

        collectionbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                final Dialog d = new Dialog(getActivity());

                d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                d.setContentView(R.layout.due_collection_popup);
                // d.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                final EditText et = (EditText) d
                        .findViewById(R.id.etduecollectionamount);

                d.findViewById(R.id.btnCollectionOk).setOnClickListener(
                        new OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                dueAmmount = et.getText().toString();
                                if (dueAmmount != null) {
                                    if (!(dueAmmount.equals(""))) {

                                        int incremental_position = position + 1;

                                        // creating a object of duecollection
                                        odi = new DueCollection();
                                        odi.setAmount(dueAmmount);

                                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
                                                "dd MMMM,yyyy");
                                        String currentDate = sdf
                                                .format(new Date());
                                        odi.setDate(currentDate);
                                        Payment payObj = Entity
                                                .query(Payment.class)
                                                .where("_id='"
                                                        + incremental_position
                                                        + "'").execute();
                                        odi.setPayment_id(payObj);

                                        om = Entity
                                                .query(OrderModel.class)
                                                .where("_id='"
                                                        + incremental_position
                                                        + "'").execute();
                                        odi.setOrder_id(om);
                                        odi.save();

                                        arrayDueDetail.add(odi);

                                        // *** duecollection obj creation ends
                                        // here
                                        total = 0;

                                        dueDetailAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        for (int i = 0; i < arrayDueDetail
                                                .size(); i++) {

                                            double dueAmount = Integer
                                                    .parseInt(arrayDueDetail
                                                            .get(i).getAmount());
                                            total += dueAmount;

                                        }

                                        String DueOnOrder = arrayPayment.get(
                                                position).getInitialDue();

                                        double remainingdue = Double
                                                .parseDouble(DueOnOrder)
                                                - total;

                                        dueActivity.dueArray.get(position)
                                                .setAmount(remainingdue);
                                        dueActivity.dueadapter
                                                .notifyDataSetChanged();

                                        payObj.setAmount(remainingdue);
                                        payObj.setSynced("0");
                                        payObj.save();

                                        // set the total remaining due to the
                                        // header textview

                                        String totalduecollection = amountFormatter(total);
                                        TotalCollectedDue.setText("BDT "
                                                + totalduecollection);
                                        dueActivity.stateStore = "" + position;

                                        setClicked = true;

                                    }

                                }

                                d.dismiss();

                            }

                        });

                d.show();
                d.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        // dueActivity.populateArray();
                        Formater fobJ = new Formater();

                        DueCollectionAsyncTask dcat = new DueCollectionAsyncTask(
                                dueActivity, "" + odi.getOrder_id().getId(), ""
                                        + odi.getPayment_id().getOutlet_id()
                                                .getId(), dueAmmount, fobJ
                                        .getDateinPrefferedFormat());
                        dcat.execute();

                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // dueActivity.header.performClick();

        dueDetailList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewDueDetails);

        dueDetailAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                // if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.due_amounts_duedetails_product_items, null);
                // }

                TextView dueFragproduct = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvduefragDate);
                TextView dueFragDueCollectionAmmount = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvduefragProductAmmount);

                dueFragproduct.setText(arrayDueDetail.get(position).getDate());

                DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
                String commaformatedstring = ""
                        + arrayDueDetail.get(position).getAmount();

                dueFragDueCollectionAmmount.setText("BDT "
                        + commaformatedstring);

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arrayDueDetail.get(position);

            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return arrayDueDetail.size();
            }

        };

        dueDetailList.setAdapter(dueDetailAdapter);
        dueDetailList.setDivider(null);
        dueDetailList.setDividerHeight(0);
        setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(dueDetailList);
    }

    /****
     * Method for Setting the Height of the ListView dynamically. Hack to fix
     * the issue of not showing all the items of the ListView when placed inside
     * a ScrollView
     ****/
    public void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null)
            return;

        int desiredWidth = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(),
                MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
        int totalHeight = 0;
        View view = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
            if (i == 0)
                view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            view.measure(desiredWidth, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight
                + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }

    public void confirmationDialog(String msg, String title, final Dialog d) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                getActivity());
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(msg);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(title);

        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        d.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        alertDialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog2 = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog2.show();
        Button nbutton = alertDialog2
                .getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        nbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#47b96b"));
        Button pbutton = alertDialog2
                .getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        pbutton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e06165"));

        int textViewId = alertDialog2.getContext().getResources()
                .getIdentifier("android:id/alertTitle", null, null);
        TextView tv = (TextView) alertDialog2.findViewById(textViewId);
        tv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.coral_blue));
    }

    public String amountFormatter(double number) {
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###");
        String totalduecollection = formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(""
                + number));
        return totalduecollection;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

## The button displays a dialog through which ListView inside the fragment gets populated.

not exactly clear to me. Did you meant inside your dialog you have some action that reflects on the fragment lisview?

## have to click the parent list view item again to see the fragment and its content. I want the Fragment view and its updated content remain viewed after the dialog is dismissed

What i understand here u are doing something inside child view fragment that reflects on parent view list item, you are expecting the parent item data to be updated in view and also keeping the view state here u meant to be opened the parent item as it was (when u are updating the something inside fragment or dialog whatever)

My primary answer is you keep somehow keep the position to a member reference of the activity class where you actually setting the parent list in parent item onClick callback.

keep this position and later what you have to is to call a method inside adapter to pass the position to set a perform clic on item view

you may get a hints from this link..

http://blog.wittchen.biz.pl/how-to-highlight-and-click-on-listview-item-in-android-programmatically/

Comment: use comments section to clarify the question then answer it properly

Comment: Thanks K.Anam for your answer. I think you got what I wanted to say. But I didnot understand what you meant by "keep the position to a member reference of the activity class where you actually setting the parent list in parent item onClick callback". Other than that I have already done everything you mentioned and it is not working. I want to keep the parent list view remain open after I add anything to child fragment listview.

Comment: set a callback interface inside the adapter of the listview that you are concern of performing a click after regenerating, pass the position inside getview method of that adapter through interface. You will use this interface callback back in the activity where you initializing the listview and get that posiotion by that callback and assign it to a global refference.

Comment: Initially this refference will be null until you ever click on listview item. So inside adapter in getview check if selectedPositon is null then it will do as would do and it it get a position that match the current position passed by getView than u do a performItemClick on that view.